# Git lists my LICENSE and README as removed, but they are still there?

Tags: git, dot-files, github

thanks for reading!

I was starting to setup my **dotfiles configuration with git and GitHub** and came across a problem:
I am using my `$HOME` as my git work tree
and have the `.git`-directory in my `$HOME/.dotfiles`-directory, by using an alias:

```bsh
alias dotfiles="git --git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/.git/ --work-tree=$HOME"
```

I created a **new Repository on GitHub** and added the *LICENSE* and the *README* there. When I clone my Repository like this:

```bsh
git clone \<url to the repository\> $HOME/.dotfiles
```

The *LICENSE* and the *README* are located in the `.dotfiles`-directory, but the command:

```bsh
dotfiles status
```

lists them as **removed**!

I **do not** want the *LICENSE* and the *README* in my `$HOME`-directory. They should stay where they are in the `$HOME/.dotfiles`-directory.

What can I do about that?

Comment: Is it helpful to provide the real link? There is nothing in the Repository, except the LICENSE and the README.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible to have LICENSE and README file in a master branch that github and gitlab will honor (be displayed on your project home in github or gitlab), but not in your home directory. [The easiest solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63266628/12571203) is to put README in `.github` folder at project home, but it only works for [github](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-readmes).

But what I actually did to have LICENSE and README displayed at project home in gitlab and github is this:

### 1. Initiate a bare git repository or replicate existing repository

First initiate a bare git repo for xadf and make initial commits without readme and/or license, and make your alias. The alias can be anything you want (eg. `dotfiles`), but I use `gitdf` so it is easier to type.

```
# Initialize a bare git directory
git init --bare $HOME/.dotfiles

# Sets up an alias so you don't have to type long commands
alias gitdf='git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME'

# Adds a remote where you'd push your changes
gitdf remote add origin git@gitlab.com:yourusername/dotfiles.git

# Do not display untracked files (it would be a ton of untracked files in an actual home tree
gitdf config status.showUntrackedFiles no
```

Or if you already have a dotfiles repository, you may want to replicate it to your home:

```
# Clone existing repo with separate git directory (here it is ~/.dotfiles), and the work tree in a separate, temporary directory .dotfiles-temp
git clone --separate-git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles https://github.com/yourusername/dotfiles.git .dotfiles-temp

# Copy the content of the temporary work tree to ~/
rsync --recursive --verbose --exclude '.git' .dotfiles-temp/ $HOME/

# Remove the temporary work tree
rm --recursive .dotfiles-temp

# Sets up an alias so you don't have to type long commands
alias gitdf='git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME'

# Sets remote directory
gitdf remote set-url origin git@github.com:yourusername/dotfiles.git
```

Note that you may need to add the alias to your `.bashrc` so it will persist for each login.

### 2. Then we make a branch

This is the actual branch you would have checked out in your real home tree. Say, a `home` branch.

```
# Make branch 'home'
gitdf checkout -b home

# You may need to also add the branch to gitlab or github
gitdf push --set-upstream origin home
```

### 3. In branch master, adds README and LICENSE

Then in branch master, you can safely adds a readme file and a license if you like. This will only be used to provide information in project home at gitlab or github. This file will not be present at commit history of branch home, and **should never be introduced in your home branch.**

```
# Switch back to branch 'master'
gitdf checkout master

# Make readme and license
touch ~/LICENSE ~/README.md

# Add them to your bare git repo
gitdf add LICENSE README.md

# Commit
gitdf commit

# Push
gitdf push
```

### 4. Only make changes to actual working branch

Then move back to branch `home`, this should be the actual checked out branch for your dotfiles, where a readme file or a LICENSE file is never present in its commit history.

```
gitdf checkout home
```

### Post set up

Afterwards, changes to config files are done from `home` branch only, or any branch derived from branch `home`. You may need to occasionally (or routinely) merged them to master:

```
# Go to branch master
gitdf checkout master

# merge branch home to branch master
gitdf merge home

# push to remote
gitdf push
```

Since branch home does not have `LICENSE` and `README.md`, the merge will not result in conflicts.

But you should never do it the other way around (eg. from branch `home`, `gitdf merge master`), as it will also add `LICENSE` and `README.md` to your working home directory.

### Multiple machine-specific configurations in each specific branch

As an added bonus, you may want to derive branch `home` for other specific uses (for example in branch `work` that is supposed to be based from `home` but with work-specific configs):

```
# Check if we're in branch home
gitdf status -sb

# Checkout to branch home if we are not
gitdf checkout home

# Note that the -b flag means make branch if it does not exist
gitdf checkout -b work

# Add new branch to remote
gitdf push --set-upstream origin work

# Configure or add work-specific changes then commit
gitdf add .config/work/related/configfile
gitdf commit

# Push to remote
gitdf push
```

Later when you make changes in your `home` branch, all you have to do to also have it in your `work` branch is just:

```
# move to branch work
gitdf checkout work

# merge branch home to branch home
gitdf merge home

# Push to remote
gitdf push
```

If you have other branch (all branched from `home`, meaning you have to start from branch `home` and make the new branch), like `laptop`, you can also merge home to them when necessary. You can also merge the changes made there to `home` if needed.

Though, really, I would advise to make shared configs from `home` and later merge them to necessary branch and `master`.

Therefore, you can visualize the merge direction like this:

```
master < home <> work
              <> laptop
```

> only merge home to master, work, or laptop, or from work, laptop, to home, but never merge master to home.

### Real life application

As a shameless plug, you can see how I set up this git alias methods in my [dotfiles repository](https://gitlab.com/heno72/xadf/). It is a more polished and moderately sophisticated implementation of the steps described above. To install that, all I have to do is to download the installer and controller script ([xadf](https://gitlab.com/heno72/xadf/-/raw/master/.local/bin/xadf)), make it executable, and place it somewhere in my PATH.

```bash
# Make directory, if it isn't present already
mkdir -p ~/.local/bin

# Download the executable into your local bin directory
wget -O ~/.local/bin/xadf https://gitlab.com/heno72/xadf/-/raw/master/.local/bin/xadf

# Make it executable
chmod +x ~/.local/bin/xadf

# Export path to local bin if it isn't set up already
PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH

# Install xadf minimally
xadf --minimal-install
```

The script can take care of step 1 (replication), checks out to a working branch (default to `trunk`, equivalent to `home` branch in my example above), including generation of configuration file for future use (alias and some functions) in `~/.config/xadf`:

```bash
# initialize, configure, load, and manage
xadf --init-bare --seat ~/.dotfiles
xadf --custom-install --seat ~/.dotfiles
. ~/.bashrc
xadf config status.showUntrackedFiles no
```

Or if you already have your own bare git repository available in a remote:

```bash
# Clone and configure from a custom url, load, and manage
xadf -i -s git@gitlab.com:heno72/xadf-gb.git --seat ~/.dotfiles
. ~/.bashrc
xadf status -sb
```

If you already have your bare git directory in your home folder, you can use xadf to manage them instead with:

```bash
xadf --custom-install --seat ~/.dotfiles
. ~/.bashrc
```

After installation (and .bashrc is sourced), I can use the script like any git commands:

```bash
# Adds a new config file to tracked file
xadf add .config/new/config/file

# Commit changes
xadf commit

# Push changes to remote
xadf push

# Change working branch
xadf checkout newbranch
```

Or some predetermined actions:

```bash
xadf -l         # list all tracked files
xadf -l .config # list all tracked files in ~/.config
```